# Python JSON dump formatting escaping quotes

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am trying to create a json object from the following fields in python 3.6

```
jsonobject={}

jsonobject['state']="[\"Complete\"]"

print(json.dumps(jsonobject))
```

I want the output to look like

```
{"state": ["Complete"]}
```

I have tried to escape the quotes, but that just seems to preserve the escape in the output as well. Any ideas on how I can force this in python?

Thanks!

Comment: Why specifically do you want the output to look like that? Aren't you going to run into issues consuming the output?

Comment: Good catch...had a made a mistake in my output format. Now I have corrected it, and an api I am posting to needs it in the format shown above. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you escaping the `list` ? You want the `list` ? or in a `str` ? `>>> jsonobject['state']= ["Complete"]
>>> json.dumps(jsonobject)
'{"state": ["Complete"]}'`

Comment: @han solo, thats perfect, this solution worked fine. Thank you! I have upvoted the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place **complete** inside a **list**

```
import json

jsonobject={}
jsonobject['state']= ["Complete"]
print(json.dumps(jsonobject))
```

Result

```
{"state": ["Complete"]}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just deserialize the value within the assignment statement?

```
jsonobject={}

jsonobject['state']=json.loads("[\"Complete\"]")

print(json.dumps(jsonobject))
```